# Visual Studio won't remove Apple's 2FA

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a personal copy of Windows 10, with Visual Studio 2022 downloaded on it that I use for work. I had been using it to build company 'A's iOS app through a Mac Mini on my LAN. I now am working for company 'B' which has given me their own subscription to Visual Studio.

But whatever I try I cannot get rid of this 2FA pop up for my Apple account on company 'A'.

I don't think however it's interfering with my ability to use VS. It's just annoying having to close it every time I open up and I also want to ensure I don't have anything from my old company still on my PC.

I've tried an entirely clean VS installation as well as made sure everything under Accounts is gone from my Visual Studio instance.[image]